# Correct way of updating plugins for webapplications hosted on linux

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

I am developing a plugin for PrestaShop, it works but the issue is with its autoupdate. Sometimes it fails on customers server due to permissions issues.

The plugin is downloaded as a zip(using php/curl) and then unzipped as plugin_temp using by a php script, then renamed to plugin. As I have been told during this process, either the perms change or the ownership changes.

What is the correct way of handling such an update ? Should the zip be extracted to 
/tmp ? 
I am guessing since a large number of web applications have autoupdating plugins there must be some sort of standard procedure..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two Answers:

- zip files do not store unix owner or permssion info.  Use a tar file instead.

There are several Q&As on Stack Overflow on this topic, including:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633488/can-i-store-unix-permissions-in-a-zip-file-built-with-apache-ant

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735297/maintain-file-and-folder-permissions-inside-archives

- The correct way to handle the update is to write an installer script that the user can, e.g., upload and run from a ssh session - web sites should not have permissions to overwrite their own script files (or .htaccess files, or add new executable scripts, etc). I realise this may be difficult or impossible on many web-hosting services, but it is important to realise that it is a huge security hole.

Comment: Thanks for replying! what if the user can't use ssh (shared hosting/noob user)? Also wordpress has permission to overwite their own script? right ?

Comment: many web-hosting environments are sub-optimal, unless you (and your users) can avoid them entirely,  you just do what you have to do to work within their flaws - which is why i gave you the pragmatic "use a tar file" answer.  a server can be set up so that wordpress can overwrite its own scripts, but it doesn't have to be.  well-run sites operated by people who care about security don't set it up that way.

Comment: Wait! If I pack the files as 777 in a tar, then send it over to our customers servers, where it is installed by tar xzf , those files will retain 777 and hence would be easily updateable ?? This would be perfect!